# Are dynamic urls with static authority are safe?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

From [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#restrictions-on-wildcards-in-redirect-uris):

> Though it's possible to set a redirect URI with a wildcard by using the manifest editor, we strongly recommend you adhere to section 3.1.2 of RFC 6749 and use only absolute URIs.

Now they give example where the authority is dynamic (`https://*.contoso.com`).
In my case, only the path is dynamic like: `https://example.com/users/{id}/profile`

Is it safe to use a wildcard in the redirect URI this case: `https://example.com/users/*/profile`?

Should I need to put other security checks because of using a wildcard in the redirect URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs your own feeling, I can just tell you if you use a wildcard in the redirect URI like `https://example.com/users/*/profile`, the user can be redirected to any `redirect_uri` configured in the OAuth 2.0 authorization URI after authorization e.g. [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code), which matches `https://example.com/users/*/profile`, e.g. `https://example.com/users/test/profile`.

And you should note Wildcard URIs are only allowed for apps that are configured to sign in only work or school accounts in an organization's Azure AD tenant.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I need my app to work with other tenants (multi-tenant). I changed the manifest and seems like it's working. should I be worried?

Comment: @Michael Did you try to use a personal account to login? I don't think it will work, as the doc said `Wildcard URIs are currently unsupported in app registrations configured to sign in personal Microsoft accounts and work or school accounts. `

Comment: No, I don't need personal account access.

Comment: @Michael If so, basically it should be secure, but still recommend you to use absolute url via RFC.